# Symbol for permutations in MathJax

Tags: support, mathjax

In the basic tutorial on MathJax, I'm unable to find the symbol for permutations. Could someone please enlighten me on this ?

Comment: Permutations as in $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$? I know of no universally used symbol for those, sometimes $(n)_k$ is used.

Comment: If you mean [two-line notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Definition_and_one-line_notation), you can use matrices or arrays for that. Copied from Wikipedia: $\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
2 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$ See also [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/how-to-input-matrices-when-posting-questions-at-math-stackexchange) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5023#5023). (The second link has many formulas, it is better not to open it on slow/mobile devices.)

Comment: So I guess shall have to use $_n$P$_k$ or P(n,k)

Comment: @Fischer: I see, unlike a special symbol for combinations, none universal for permutations  exist. Thanks.